# SQL Adding rows to my dataset as placeholders for missing groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Looking for some help on this.  Lets my dataset has 3 columns: Category, SubCategory and Value.

Each Category does NOT contain every SubCategory, and if it does NOT, I want to add a new row / placeholder for that missing Category/SubCategory combination with a value of 0.

For example:

```
SELECT distinct(SubCategory) From MyTable returns:
SubCategory-A
SubCategory-B
SubCategory-C
SubCategory-D
```

Let's say Category1 contains SubCategory-A and SubCategory-C.  I want to add placeholders/new rows for the missing SubCategories B and D, so ultimately my results would look like (order doesn't matter):

```
Category1     SubCategory-A      100
Category1     SubCategory-C      125
Category1     SubCategory-B      0      << new row / placeholder
Category1     SubCategory-D      0      << new row / placeholder
```

I have multiple Categories I'd like to apply this to.  Can anyone help me with this?  Much appreciated!

Comment: "Lets say each of my table has 3 columns" can you please name your tables and elaborate more on the structure of it?

Comment: You want a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `COALESCE` to swap `NULL` for 0

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  I updated the statement above.  Was meant to read 1 table, or 1 dataset, and only 3 columns.

Comment: Are you looking to retrieve a "complete" data set, or do you need to add (insert) missing rows to the source table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

First insert All distinct categoryId and subcategoryid into a temp table from the target table

```
SELECT DISTINCT CategoryIds, SubCategoryIds into #t1 FROM TableC
```

Then Insert the values into Target table

```
INSERT INTO TableC(CategoryIds, SubCategoryIds,Value)
SELECT CategoryIds, SubCategoryIds,0 FROM
(SELECT Distinct CategoryIds From TableA) A 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Distinct SubCategoryIds From TableA) B 
EXCEPT 
SELECT CategoryIds, SubCategoryIds, 0 FROM #t1
```

Comment: Thanks to all the responses, I'm sure all / many of the responses would have worked.  I just happend to use a variation of this one to get what I was looking for.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version.

The performance of whichever version you go with will be impacted if your table is large (but only if it can be measured in 100s of megabytes, I'd guess)

```
;WITH cteGaps as (
    select
       cat.Category
      ,subcat.SubCategory
     from (--  All categories
           select distinct Category
            from MyTable
          ) cat
      cross join (--  All subcategories
                  select distinct SubCategory
                   from MyTable
                 ) subcat
    except select
       Category
      ,SubCategory
     from MyTable
    )
INSERT MyTable (Category, SubCategory, Value)
 select Category, SubCategory, 0
  from cteGaps
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would use. Similar to the others, but in my mind a bit easier to read and understand. Also avoids using a CTE, which I believe is unnecessary for this. I also prefer `group by` over `distinct` in most cases, but again, just personal preference.

```
SELECT a.*, Value = ISNULL(b.Value, 0)
FROM (  -- returns all pairs of category and subcategory
    SELECT *
    FROM (
         SELECT Category
         FROM MyTable
         GROUP BY Category
    ) a
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT SubCategory 
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY SubCategory
    ) b
) a
LEFT JOIN MyTable b
ON a.Category = b.Category and a.SubCategory = b.SubCategory
```

Alias the subqueries however you wish - I was lazy and used `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
SELECT a.Category,c.SubCategory,ISNULL(b.Value,0) AS Value
FROM MyTable a 
CROSS JOIN Mytable c
LEFT JOIN MyTable b
On c.SubCategory = b.SubCategory
AND a.category = b.Category
GROUP BY   a.Category,c.SubCategory,b.Value
```